# Json.parse Syntax Error

Tags: json

I've got code.

```
{
 s: "ok",
 t: [1386493512, 1386493572, 1386493632, 1386493692],
 c: [42.1, 43.4, 44.3, 42.8]
}
```

Why it return code
`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 2 column 4 of the JSON data`

Comment: For starters that's not valid JSON. Property names have to be enclosed in double quotes. See [json.org](http://json.org/) for more details...

Comment: "I've got code." Good. Where is that code? What JS is calling `JSON.parse`?

Comment: that's not json, that's javascript. in json, object keys **MUST** be quoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript the keys are presumed to be strings so keys do not need to be in quotes, however in JSON they do. You should change your code to look like

```
{
 "s": "ok",
 "t": [1386493512, 1386493572, 1386493632, 1386493692],
 "c": [42.1, 43.4, 44.3, 42.8]
}
```